# Creating a view using subquery,with alias for columns in ORACLE 9i!

Tags: oracle, oracle9i

This is my query,

```
  CREATE VIEW employee_vu AS(
  SELECT employee_id,last_name "employee",department_id
  FROM employees);
```

I am giving alias of columns in lower case ,and in it is stored in lower case
after doing desc i have confirmed.

But when i am trying to select this column employee :error occurs

> EMPLOYEE: invalid identifier

Since all column name is stored in upper case ,is this the problem,Please explain what is the concept behind!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You would need to select it using double quotes and matching case:

```
select employee_id, "employee", department_id from employees;
```

That's why creating columns with double quoted identifiers is considered bad practice in Oracle.